Require multiple strings
I'd like to get rid of all those bots which are attacking my website.
Here's my conf :
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'Go-http-client/1.1'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'Go-http-client/2.0'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'Custom-AsyncHttpClient'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'python-requests/2.21.0'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'python-requests/2.22.0'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'python-requests/2.23.0'
    Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'l9explore/1.2.2'
</RequireAll>

The problem is that from my logs, I've seen that there are 15 different python-requests version numbers.

"python-requests/2.21.0"
"python-requests/2.22.0"
"python-requests/2.23.0"
"python-requests/2.24.0"
"python-requests/2.25.1"
"python-requests/2.26.0"
"python-requests/2.27.1"
"python-requests/2.28.1"
"python-requests/2.28.2"
"python-requests/2.31.0"
"python-requests/2.32.0"
"python-requests/2.32.1"
"python-requests/2.32.2"
"python-requests/2.32.3"
"python-requests/2.6.0"

Is there a way to say "all python-requests" ? I've tried the following but apachectl configtest complains :
Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ 'python-requests'
Thank you

expr can be followed by any valid expression. You can use a !~, but it must be followed by a regex in the form /regex/ or m#regex#.
Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ m#python-requests/#

